Potential flow in 3D or higher
The potential flow theory in 2D is described from the incompressibility condition
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}{\nabla \cdot \mathbf u =0},&&{\mathbf u=\nabla \varphi}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
$$\nabla^2\varphi=0$$
with the Cauchy-Riemann equations
$${\displaystyle {\begin{aligned}u&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial x}}={\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial y}},&v&={\frac {\partial \varphi }{\partial y}}=-{\frac {\partial \psi }{\partial x}}\,.\end{aligned}}}$$
From there we can obtain practically all we need to model the flow.
We draw the velocity field using the vector potential $\psi$, since the vector potential is colinear with the velocity field.
Lamb and Batchelor define the stream function  $\psi$ as follows: ${\displaystyle \psi (x,y,t)=\int _{A}^{P}\left(u\,\mathrm {d} y-v\,\mathrm {d} x\right)}$ .
Where the velocity field is defined with :
$${\displaystyle \quad \mathbf {u} ={\begin{bmatrix}u(x,y,t)\\v(x,y,t)\\0\end{bmatrix}}.}$$
I heard that the stream-function $\psi$ is not defined for dimensions higher than 2.
Why is that?
How do we draw the velocity field in dimensions higher than 2 if $\psi$ is not defined and we need it to draw the velocity field, since it is colinear with the velocity vector?

Your question is a little vague.  What setup do you want in dimension 3, and what kind of analysis are you interested in making?  The main issue is that in dimension 2 ODEs are fairly tame due to  structural theorems like Poincare-Bendixson.  In dimension 3 there are no such theorems, and ODEs have far more wild characteristics.  But if your setup is tame-enough there are certainly things you can say.  But I don't know what kinds of problems you are interested in.

@RyanBudney Hi, I actually changed my question a little now. I am actually interested now in why the streamfunction $\psi$ can not be defined in 3D? Furthermore, how can we solve potential flow problems without it than, if we use it to draw the velocity field.

What definition are you using for the "stream function"?  Is it just the solution to your PDE?

Lamb and Batchelor define the stream function  $\psi$ as follows: ${\displaystyle \psi (x,y,t)=\int _{A}^{P}\left(u,\mathrm {d} y-v,\mathrm {d} x\right)}$ . It is a vector potential. It is defined for $R^2$, but what do we do when we want to model $R^3$ flow and we don't want to solve the full NS equations, but model with potential flow.

What does that mean?  Your right hand side has a u and v, but the left-hand side does not.

The velocity field is defined like this: ${\displaystyle \quad \mathbf {u} ={\begin{bmatrix}u(x,y,t)\v(x,y,t)\0\end{bmatrix}}.}$

So that u and v depend on x, y, and t.

Apologies, but I am not following.  It feels like there is a lot of hidden assumptions perhaps buried in your notation that I'm not familiar with.

It is alright. My apologies if my presentation was not clear enough. I think it is best to let it be for now. Thank you anyways for the responds. Cheers
